# Query an array with must match

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an index of documents. The index contains body of documents and the type of document e.g pdf, jpeg, png etc. I can query the index with a word and one document type using must just fine.

```
                $params = [
                'index' => 'trial2',
                'type' => '_doc',
                'body' => [
                  'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                      'must' => [
                        [ 'match' => [ 'file.extension' => "png" ] ],
                        [ 'match' => [ 'content' => "abc" ] ],
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ];
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9iPl.png) The challenge is, I would like to query the index still using must but with an array of document type (png but jpeg, gif, svg, tiff) so that I classify it as an image. How do I replace png with an array so that at lease one is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If `file.extension` is of `text` type:

Just add more tokens next to [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). Make sure you go through [this (Analysis)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and to [this (Analyzer)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html)  to understand how it works internally.

```
POST my_png/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "file.extension": "jpg jpeg png"        <---- Note this.
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## If `file.extension` is of `keyword` type (Recommended)

Or if you have a `keyword` sibling in `file.extension.keyword`, you can make use of [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
POST my_png/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {                         <---- Terms Query
            "file.extension.keyword": [      <---- Or 'file.extension' field, whichever must of be type `keyword`
              "jpg",
              "jpeg",
              "png"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Based on your requirement, I like to think that you must be using the second option as for exact matches, you would need to use `Terms Query` on `keyword` field.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi need your help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730188/how-to-get-exact-text-match-from-elasticsearch-if-the-query-is-between-quotes

Comment: @Denn could you check the answer I've posted in that link you've mentioned. Let me know if you need any further help!!

Comment: Thank you so much.. you've clarified a concept I was not getting. I appreciate.. Maybe comment something on my reply?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "terms" query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

The terms query returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field.