# How to get exact text match from elasticsearch if the query is between quotes

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I implemented elasticsearch using php for binary documents (fscrawler). It works just fine with the default settings. I can search the documents for the word I want and I get results that are case insensitive. However, I now want to do exact matches i.e on top of the current search, if the query is enclosed in quotes, I want to get results that only match the query exactly.. even case sensitive.

My mapping looks like this:

```
"settings": {
"number_of_shards": 1,
"index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000,
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "fscrawler_path": {
      "tokenizer": "fscrawler_path"
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "fscrawler_path": {
      "type": "path_hierarchy"
    }
  }
}
.
.
.
  "content": {
    "type": "text",
    "index": true
  },
```

My query for the documents looks like this:

```
    if ($q2 == '') {
    $params = [
        'index' => 'trial2',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'match_phrase' => [
                        'content' => $q
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $query = $client->search($params);
    $data['q'] = $q;
}
```

For exact matches(does not work):

```
    if ($q2 == '') {
        $params = [
            'index' => 'trial2',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'filter' =>[
                        'term' => [
                            'content' => $q
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $query = $client->search($params);
        $data['q'] = $q;
    }
```

content field is the body of the document. How do I implement the exact match for a specific word or phrase in the content field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `content` field, what I understand, would be significantly large as many documents may be more than 2-3 MB and that's a lot of words.

There'd be no point in using `keyword` field in order to do exact match as per the answer to your earlier question where I referred to using `keyword`. You should use [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatype for exact match ***only if your data is structured***

What I understand is the `content` field you have is unstructured. In that case you would want to make use of [Whitespace Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) on your `content` field.

Also for exact phrase match you make take a look at [Match Phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) query.

Below is a sample index, documents and queries that would suffice your use case.

### Mapping:

```
PUT mycontent_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content":{
        "type":"text",
        "analyzer": "whitespace"            <----- Note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST mycontent_index/_doc/1
{
  "content": """
      There is no pain you are receding
      A distant ship smoke on the horizon
      You are only coming through in waves
      Your lips move but I can't hear what you're saying
  """
}

POST mycontent_index/_doc/2
{
  "content": """          
      there is no pain you are receding
      a distant ship smoke on the horizon
      you are only coming through in waves
      your lips move but I can't hear what you're saying
  """
}
```

### Phrase Match:(To search a sentence with words in order)

```
POST mycontent_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {                   <---- Note this for phrase match
            "content": "There is no pain"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Match Query:

```
POST mycontent_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {                          <---- Use this for token based search
            "content": "there"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that your response should be accordingly.

For exact match for a word, just use a simple [Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query.

Note that when you do not specify any analyzer, ES by default uses [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) and this would cause all the tokens to be converted into lower case before storing them in Inverted Index. However, [Whitespace Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) *would not* convert the tokens into lower case. As a result `There` and `there` are stored as two different tokens in your ES index.

I'm assuming you are aware of [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and [Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) concepts and if not I'd suggest you to go through the links as that will help you know more on what I'm talking about.

### Updated Answer:

Post understanding your requirements, there is no way you can apply multiple analyzers on a single field, so basically you have two options:

**Option 1:** Use multiple indexes

**Option 2:** Use [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) in your mapping as shown below:

That way, your script or service layer would have the logic of pushing to different index or field depending on your input value(ones having double inverted comma and ones that are simple tokens)

### Multi Field Mapping:

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{ 
   "mappings":{ 
      "properties":{ 
         "content":{ 
            "type":"text",                     <--- Field with standard analyzer
            "fields":{ 
               "whitespace":{ 
                  "type":"text",               <--- Field with whitespace
                  "analyzer":"whitespace"       
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Ideally, I would prefer to have the first solution i.e making use of multiple indexes with different mapping, however I would strongly advise you to revisit your use-case because it doesn't make sense in managing querying like this but again its your call.

**Note:** *A cluster of single node* that's the worst possible option you can ever do and specially not for Production.

I'd suggest you ask that in separate question detailing your docs count, growth rate over next 5 years or something and would your use case be more read heavy or write intensive? Is that cluster something other teams may also would want to leverage. I'd suggest you to read more and discuss with your team or manager to get more clarity on your scenarios.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Kamal, thank you so much for your guidance.. your example works fine but I don't get my previous results. As you've said, when I don't add an analyzer, standard analyzer is used but when I put the whitespace analyzer, all words are left as they are... My challenge is, I kinda want to get both results.. i.e I am querying from a form and if I just enter the word cat then this should give the results of the standard analyzer, but if I put the words between quotes "cat", then the results should be from the whitespace analyzer. How do I combine this analyzers?

Comment: @Denn I need more more clarifications. Would this scenario be specific only for `content` field or would you want it for all the fields or few in your index. How large are your documents and whats your cluster size?

Comment: yeah I think for now this scenario is specific to the 'content' field.. My documents size ranges from single page papers of a few sentences to books with several pages (~100). Am working with a cluster of a single node..

Comment: kindly advice me on my configuration (cluster) if you think I should do it differently

Comment: @Denn, was the updated answer useful, were you able to resolve or implement this solution?

Comment: yes sir .. the multi-field option worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: so everything is running well.. I am trying to index about 7TB of data but my indexing stops after sometime (about 2.6gb index size).. Does elasticsearch has limitations on memory?

Comment: Hi @Kamal, using the above code i.e whitespace analyzer, is there a way i can male it case insensitive? So that Car, car and CAR are all returned positively.